# The from url pattern with key word '#', it can not work

Tags: forms, url, url-rewriting

e.g.:
`<rule>
    <from>^/create#name=(.*)$</from>
    <to>/page/new/success.jsp?name=$1</to>
</rule>`

when I enter the uri like "/create#name=elvis",it cannot rewrite and forward to new address,
how can I do now , how to transcoding the sign '#'

???

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work (escaping the `#` sign)?

Adding type Forward:

```
<rule>
  <from>/create\#name=(.*)</from>
  <to type="forward">/page/new/success.jsp?name=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Adding type Redirect:

```
<rule>
  <from>/create\#name=(.*)</from>
  <to type="redirect">/page/new/success.jsp?name=$1</to>
</rule>
```